# Bootstrap tabs block after hovering over theme

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got 4 verticals pills and they show the content when I hover over them but after I hover one time over them they're not working anymore.
I've made a demo on Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEqNyw).

My goal is to show the active test 1 tab by default and the other (test 2 3 and 4) when we click or hover over them.

```
   <div class="container">
  <h3>Vertical Pills</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the js file

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '[data-toggle="tab"]', function () {
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Comment: please, add code snippet instead pasting code, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vertical pill `il` elements are not placed in a `ul` element but in a `div` element. Changing the `div` element to a `ul` element fixed your bug.

You can check out a working example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEZXom.